# Magento collection compate two columns

Tags: magento

I'm sticking on this couple of days. I have custom grid in admin area where I need to display Product names  and descriptions for two languages (store views).
Here is my _prepareCollection function:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $collection =
            Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('short_description')
        ;

        if ($store->getId()) {
            //$collection->setStoreId($store->getId());
            $adminStore = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
            $collection->addStoreFilter($store);
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'name',
                'catalog_product/name',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $adminStore
            );

            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'custom_name',
                'catalog_product/name',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'left',
                $store->getId()
            );

            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'custom_short_description',
                'catalog_product/short_description',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'left',
                $store->getId()
            );
        }

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this;
    }
```

Is there any way to filter the collection (before parent::_prepareCollection();) to select only rows where name is not equal to custom_name. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You no need to join . Just Filter product collection by Store ID . As magento automatically fetch data from flat table created by store ID. So only just use $collection->addStoreFilter($store); 
Thanks 
Avik

Comment: Where in your answer is solution for comparing column 'name' with column 'custom_name'?

Comment: As i have understood you want product name and description depending upon store view . So please use this $collection =
            Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addStoreFilter($store); You no need to join as this query will return data from catalog_product_flat_X tables. Magento stores store view data under flat tables for faster execution so you no need to join with every attribute value. Hope this will help you . Thanks